# How to add Redis configuration in express-request-proxy node package

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I'm using "express-request-proxy" node package for adding proxy for the HTTP requests. I have enabled the Redis cache which works fine in my local server.

Here is how I am loading the Redis packages in my local as suggested in the documentation (https://github.com/4front/express-request-proxy#caching):

```
var redis = require('redis');
require('redis-streams')(redis);
```

However when I'm pushing the app to cloud, I'm seeing the following error:

```
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

I have the Redis server details of the cloud but I'm not quite sure how to configure the host, port and password here.

Could someone suggest on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by adding the following:

```
  var redisConfig = {
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 6379
        };
  redis.createClient(redisConfig);
```

It's pretty straightforward, not sure how I missed it earlier.